# Is there any reasons to use axios instead ES6 fetch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

Studied the documentation of axios and of ES6 fetch I found than both are quite similar and have experienced a strong influence of $.ajax and its shorthands.

Main advantage of axios is browser support.

So am I right that if I use babel-polyfill - there is no reasons to use axios?

Comment: There's a bunch of reasons to use Axios. Fetch feels like low-level API that weren't designed to be comfortable and lacks a lot of features that Axios has - interceptors, cancellation, testability... This includes most of those that can be seen on Axios page, https://github.com/axios/axios#features The question is off-topic. Just try both in action and see yourself. A single fetch advantage that can be noted is that it seamlessly works with service workers because it returns Response object (it isn't too convenient in other cases).

Comment: A link from deleted answer that may help, https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5

Comment: Axios is for the lazy and uninitiated.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A few reasons for using Axios over Fetch:

1. Ability to monitor request progress

This is more of a question between XMLHttpRequest (which powers axios) or Fetch API.

Fetch API currently does not provide any way to get notified of the request progress, a feature which powers feedback mechanism for large file uploads for example.

Axios, on the other hand, has this functionality built in:

```
axios.post('/api', data, {
    onUploadProgress: ({ total, loaded }) => {
        // update progress
    }),
})
```

2. Error handling

When your backend returns `500 Internal Server Error` response code, `fetch` will not treat it any different from `200 OK`.

This is an inconvenience in most cases since all your previous assumptions of what a response would look like are no longer valid.

Most often, when receiving an erroneous response from the server you'd want to abort the processing pipeline as soon as possible, and switch to an error handling case.

```
fetch(url)
    .then(reponse => {
        if (!(status >= 200 && status < 300)) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Invalid response status"));
        }

        return response;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(/* normal processing */)
    .catch(/* error handling */);
```

This is not hard to accomplish, but you'd probably want to capture this logic under some abstraction to avoid repetition, and this brings us one step closer to Web API abstraction which is Axios.

Axios does a sane thing and rejects the promise if the response returns erroneous status. This behavior is customizable as are most of the things with axios.

3. Testing

Axios has [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios), fetch has [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock).

Both of those libraries are great but in my experience, `fetch-mock` required additional setup to get Jest to use mocked fetch over polyfilled one.

I also like that `moxios.wait()` returns a promise which will be resolved after matching the request.

4. Other features that Axios offers

For example, you can configure an interceptor which will add api key to all request parameters, or monitor active requests to show a loading screen.

---

Reasons for using one option over the other may vary from actual requirements to convenience.

If you need to monitor progress, use Axios (or XMLHttpRequest).

If you are writing a service worker, use Fetch.

Otherwise, use what's more convenient to you.

Comment: "If you are writing a service worker, use Fetch." -  for anyone wondering, it seems that Axios relies on `XMLHttpRequest`, but this API has been deprecated in favour of `Fetch` and service workers only support `Fetch`. There are plans in the future to switch Axios to use `Fetch`: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/484

Comment: @Harvey not deprecated.

Comment: @atikan Oops. Use of `XMLHttpRequest` is perhaps discouraged, but will never be deprecated.

Comment: Another difference is the ease of setting timeouts using Axios:
`axios({ method: 'post', url: '/login', timeout: 4000, data: { firstName: 'Patrick', lastName: 'Bateman' } })`. HTTP Interceptor implementations is also worth looking into further

Comment: Fetch can use the Abort Controller API to cancel requests. Also progress is coming. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController
https://javascript.info/fetch-progress

Answer (score 36):

This:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title,
      body
    })
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json()
    }

    throw new Error(res.responseText);

  })
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

can essentially be expressed by axios with this:

```
axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    title,
    body
  }).then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

So in essence:

1. No need to do `res.json()`, `res.text()` etc
2. No need to handle `res.ok` in order to catch non 200 status errors in actual promise `catch` handler.
3. No need to stringify payload, it's handled by axios by default.

Overall `axios` provides a more higher level and simple api to work with requests.

Answer (score 3):

Axios is an NPM library and therefore works on both Node.js and the browser. `fetch` is a Web API and is not available to Node. Conversely, Node.js has the `http` module and does not have the Fetch API. It also simplifies passing data and handling different types of HTTP Requests

Comment: There npm libraries that implement the `fetch` API too.

Comment: Ok, but when used on Node, it doesn't use a built-in function called `fetch`. It's a polyfill

Comment: Totally, but if it follows the spec, it's still the fetch API whether it is in a browser, or Node.

Comment: @Meghan I found your insight "`fetch` is a polyfilled on Node" to be critical, because I stumbled into issues with `fetch` on Node, that were not reproducible in browser-fetch. So thank you!

Comment: FYI, `fetch()` is coming to Node. It's already an experimental feature in Node `v17.5`, enabled with `--experimental-fetch`.